# Union and Intersection, Problem with {a}

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In some book (Deiser, Mengenlehre, 3. Aufl.) about set theory the author defines the general union and intersection:

$\cap$M = {x|for all a $\in$ M also x $\in$ a}

$\cup$M = {x|there exists some a $\in$ M with x $\in$ a}.

He then brings the example: $\cap${a} = $\cup${a} = a. If you just apply the definition it does not make sense to me. Do you see that by just applying the definition? What'd make sense is this: $\cap${{a}} = $\cup${{a}} = a. Am I right or do I make a mistake?

Comment: I find it helpful when doing this sort of question to use distinct letters in different places: so I'd replace the $a$ which are tied to the quantifiers by $p$ or something, lest I get confused when I try to do the calculation where $a$ is something definite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a few examples.

Let's say $a=\{1,2,3\}$ and $b=\{4,5,6\}$. Then:

$\cup\{a,b\}=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ (everything in either $a$ or $b$).

Now, let's look at $\cup\{a\}$. This is:

$\cup\{a\}=\{1,2,3\}$ (everything in $a$).

So, as you can see, $\cup\{a\}=a$ because they both have the same elements.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it follows from the definition.

$\bigcap\{a\}$ is by definition the set of all $x$ such that $x\in y$ for every member $y$ of the set $\{a\}$. The only member of the set $\{a\}$ is $a$, so by definition $x\in\bigcap\{a\}$ if and only if $x\in a$. The sets $\bigcap\{a\}$ and $a$ therefore have the same members and hence are the same set.

Similarly, $\bigcup\{a\}$ is by definition the set of all $x$ such that $x$ belongs to at least one member of $\{a\}$. The **only** member of $\{a\}$ is $a$, so if $x$ belongs to $\bigcup\{a\}$, then $x$ must belong to $a$. Conversely, if $x\in a$, then certainly $x$ belongs to at least one member of $\{a\}$, so $x\in\bigcup\{a\}$. Thus, $\bigcup\{a\}\subseteq a$ and $a\subseteq\bigcup\{a\}$, so $\bigcup\{a\}=a$.

Comment: And what if a = $\emptyset$? Than it's not the case anymore that $\cup${a} = $\cap${a} = a.

Comment: @Pippen: Yes, it is still the case. There is nothing in $\bigcup\{\varnothing\}$ or $\bigcap\{\varnothing\}$, because there is nothing in $\varnothing$. What do you imagine is in these sets?

Comment: Yes, I got it, I just confused the empty set with the set of an empty set. Thx a lot!

Comment: @Pippen: You’re welcome! (That’s a very common confusion when one is just starting.)

Comment: @Pippen: you can tick the green checkbox to accept an answer. That will prevent the question from getting kicked up by the system again (due to it having no accepted answer).

Answer (score 0):

To prove $\bigcup\{a\}=a$ we need to prove (i) $\bigcup\{a\}\subseteq a$; and  (ii) $a\subseteq \bigcup\{a\}$.

For (i) let $x\in\bigcup\{a\}$. Then for some $p\in\{a\}$ we have $x\in p$. But there is only one such $p$, namely $a$. So $x\in a$ and we are done.

For (ii) let $x\in a$. Then $x\in a\in \{a\}$, so by definition $x\in\bigcup\{a\}$.

[I have assumed that we have proved that $\{a\}$ (is the definition in your book $\{a\}=\{a,a\}$, where $\{a,b\}$ is already defined?) has precisely one element $a$. ]